# EF Core - Firebird Migration auto-increment problem

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, firebird, firebird-3.0, firebird-.net-provider

I'm testing the migration with EF Core with MSSQL-Server and Firebird 3.0.

I create a new table with a few fields. The key-field has the property `.ValueGeneratedOnAdd()`, but the key-field in the Firebird database doesn't get an auto-increment during the migration. It works with the MS-SQL-Server correctly.

I use the framework FirebirdSql.EntityFrameworkCore.Firebird version 6.6.0.

```
modelBuilder.Entity("GenerateCodeFromDB.DB_Modell.TblTest", b =>
{
    b.Property<long>("Id")
        .ValueGeneratedOnAdd()
        .HasColumnName("ID")
        .HasAnnotation("SqlServer:ValueGenerationStrategy", SqlServerValueGenerationStrategy.IdentityColumn);

    b.Property<DateTime?>("Date");

    b.Property<string>("Name")
        .HasMaxLength(50);

    b.Property<int?>("Number");

    b.HasKey("Id");

    b.ToTable("tblTest");
});
```

Comment: I suggest that you file a bug report on http://tracker.firebirdsql.org/browse/DNET or post to the firebird-net-provider mailing list.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel: I created a new issue on the tracker page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the solution on http://tracker.firebirdsql.org/browse/DNET-884. I have to add `.ForFirebirdUseIdentityColumns()` in OnModelCreating in the DBContext class. Now I get the auto-increment in both database-types.

It looks now like this:

```
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.HasAnnotation("ProductVersion", "2.2.4-servicing-10062")
            .ForFirebirdUseIdentityColumns()
            .ForSqlServerUseIdentityColumns();

        modelBuilder.Entity<TblTest>(entity =>
        {
            entity.HasKey(e => e.Id)
                .HasName("PK__tblTest");

            entity.Property(e => e.Name).IsUnicode(false);
        });
    }
```

After adding the migration I have to an annotation in the createTable-parameter for the second database-type I'm using. In my case I added the migration with Firebird and added the annotation for the SqlServer:

```
        migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
            name: "tblTest",
            columns: table => new
            {
                ID = table.Column<long>(nullable: false)
                    .Annotation("Fb:ValueGenerationStrategy", FbValueGenerationStrategy.IdentityColumn)       
                    .Annotation("SqlServer:ValueGenerationStrategy", SqlServerValueGenerationStrategy.IdentityColumn),
                Number = table.Column<int>(nullable: true),
                Name = table.Column<string>(unicode: false, maxLength: 50, nullable: true),
                Date = table.Column<DateTime>(nullable: true)
            },
            constraints: table =>
            {
                table.PrimaryKey("PK__tblTest", x => x.ID);
            });
```